# Как передать с @Output() декоратора объект в Angular?

Tags: angular2, typescript

Передача объекта прописана в этом файле, но код работает неправильно, выводится "[object Object]", как это исправить? Помогите, разобраться, пожалуйста

//child.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<div><input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user" placeholder = "Введите сообщение" />
  <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="adding(user, bot)">Отправить</button></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent {

@Output('AddMessage') addMessage = new EventEmitter<object>()

public adding(user_mes: string, bot_mes: string) {

this.addMessage.emit({user_mes, bot_mes});

}

}
```

//two.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'two',
  template: `<h4>Список сообщений</h4>
  <ul *ngFor="let msg of message"><li>{{msg.user}}</li><li>{{msg.bot}}</li></ul>`,
  styles: [ '' ]
 })
 export class TwoComponent  {
 @Input() message: string[];
 }
```

//app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

class Messages {

  user: string;
  bot: string;

constructor(_user: string, _bot: string) {

    this.user = _user;
    this.bot = _bot;

  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<two [message]="message"></two>
  <child (AddMessage)="addMessage($event)"></child>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public message: Messages[] = [];

  addMessage(user: string, bot: string) {
    if (user == null) {
      return;
    }
   this.message.push(new Messages(user, bot));
  }
  }
```

Comment: вы генерируете объект со свойствами `user_mes, bot_mes`, а в верхнем компоненте объявляете 2 параметра в методе `user` и `bot` - для чего? замените на `(AddMessage)="addMessage($event.user_mes, $event.bot_mes)"`

Comment: на всякий случай, ссылка на песочницу: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzhquw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Вы передаете объект, а хотите принять две строки! Причем с полями `user_mes` и `bot_mes`.
Перепишите так:

```
addMessage(event: any) {
    const { user_mes, bot_mes } = event;
    if (user_mes == null) {
      return;
    }
  this.message.push(new Messages(user_mes, bot_mes));
}
```

Comment: работает, спасибо!

Comment: Автор вопроса может пометить один из ответов «принятым».